# python heatmap for two datasets

Tags: python, heatmap

Can someone tell me how to make a heatmap to see the correlation between each two variables from two datasets (with same rwo numbers but different column numbers). something like this:

dataset A: age     length     weight

```
        2       5          7
        3       3          7
        6       9          2
```

dataset B:  a              b              c             d             e

```
        0.3    0.7     2.3    3.2    8.4
        5.2    3.2     3.4    1.1    0.4
        3.3    2.6     6.6    4.4    2.8
```

And the result heat map is like:

age

length   (color cells here)

weight

```
      a  b  c  d  e
```

I'm new in data visualization so thanks for any hint!!

Comment: longth? not length? Also, what have you tried/looked into? researched any libraries you're having issues with?

Comment: sorry about the typo! I only found python heatmap could give pair-wise correlation between the variables from the same dataset, which means the x-axis and y axis of theheatmap would contain the same lables. But since I don't want the correlations between the variables from the same dataset. I tried to concatenate the two datasets to one and then make the heatmap and select the correlations that I need. I wondered if there is any more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas already provides this functionality. 
You can put the data in a dataframe then do this, first line to create the correlation matrix, second line to create a heatmap

```
corr=dataframe.corr()
corr.style.background_gradient()
```

[background_style for pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.core.style.Styler.background_gradient.html)
[pandas correlation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html)